# Window Constantly Wants To Be On Top Of Others - Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, window, automator

My app has buttons that open automator workflows like this:

```
- (IBAction)actionname:(id)sender {
    NSTaskname = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [NSTaskname setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/automator"];
    NSArray *arguments;
    arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"/Applications/appname.app/Contents/Resources/workflowname.workflow", nil];
    [NSTaskname setArguments:arguments];
    [NSTaskname launch];                                                                             
}
```

The only problem is, that every single one appears behind the window of my app. Also, one workflow launches another app which also appears behind the window.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You should name your variable something other than “NSTaskname”, as that name implies (a) that it is a class (because its name starts with a capital letter), rather than a variable, and (b) that it refers to some kind of name, rather than an NSTask object.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use NSRunningApplication to bring your NSTask process to the front with its PID like this...

```
NSRunningApplication* app = [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier:[NSTaskname processIdentifier]];
[app activateWithOptions: NSApplicationActivateAllWindows];
```

And if you need to activate a specific application, for example your workflow that launches another app, then you could do this using the application's bundle identifier. This example will activate Safari.

```
NSArray* apps = [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.Safari"];
[(NSRunningApplication*)[apps objectAtIndex:0] activateWithOptions: NSApplicationActivateAllWindows];
```

Comment: Neither of those work. The only change is that it flashes to the other app, but then it goes right back. How about deactivating the windows in my app?

Comment: Well I gave you the idea of using NSRunningApplication to manipulate the active application. Did you look at that class and see what else it can do? I think it can help you with the idea from your comment. Check the "hide" command and others.